# Проблема с кодировкой. KeyError: '╦юё-└эфцхыхё ╦хщъхЁё'

Tags: python, list

Есть объект `MatchData`:

```
self.data = {
            'matchDate' : self.findMatchData(), // итоговые значения - строки
            'nameHome': self.findTeamName('home'), // итоговые значения - строки 
            'nameAway': self.findTeamName('away'), // итоговые значения - строки
            'pointHome': self.cutPoint('home'), 
            'pointAway': self.cutPoint('away'),
            'loser': '', // итоговые значения - строки
            'winner': '', // итоговые значения - строки
            'result': '', // итоговые значения - строки
        }
```

Прохожу циклом:

```
         for item in [matchData['nameHome'], matchData['nameAway']]: 
                if matchData['loser'] == item: 
                    self.freqList[item]['pass'] += 1 
                elif matchData['winner'] == item: 
                    self.freqList[item]['take'] += 1 
            else: 
                if matchData['loser'] == item: 
                    self.freqList[item]['pass'] = 1 
                elif matchData['winner'] == item: 
                    self.freqList[item]['take'] = 1
```

Выдаёт ошибку -

```
File "...," in addTeamInList
    self.freqList[item]['pass'] = 1
KeyError: '╦юё-└эфцхыхё ╦хщъхЁё'
```

Answer (score 0):

Немного перемудрил с типами данных. Суть была в том, что если команды нет - дать ей дефолтные данные. Если есть - прибавить к ним, но обращался не совсем верно. Поправил:

```
for item in [matchData['nameHome'], matchData['nameAway']]: 
            if self.freqList.get(item): 
                if matchData['loser'] == item: 
                    self.freqList[item]['pass'] += 1 
                elif matchData['winner'] == item: 
                    self.freqList[item]['take'] += 1 
            else: 
                if matchData['loser'] == item: 
                    self.freqList[item] = {
                        'pass': 1, 
                        'take': 0,
                    }
                elif matchData['winner'] == item: 
                    self.freqList[item] = {
                        'pass': 0, 
                        'take': 1,
                    }
```